# React Native Flatlist zIndex not working with overflow: 'visible' on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to implement a bottom-up Flatlist on iOS. To do that; I had to reverse the items, flip the list and flip the list again. It works fine but when I try to use overflow: 'visible', it goes on top of everthing (including the StatusBar) and I cannot hide it.

The code of FlatList:

```
render() {
    let data = renderMessages(this.props.comments, this.props.postId) //??
    return (
        <FlatList
          ref="listRef"
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          style={{ position: 'absolute', transform: [{ scaleY: -1 }], flexGrow: 0, overflow: 'visible', zIndex: -9999}}        
          onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          onScrollBeginDrag={() => { this.onEndReachedCalledDuringScroll = false; }}
        />
    )
  }
```

Parent:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}>
    <CommentList
        count={this.props.commentCounter[post.id] || 10}
        postId={post.id}
    />
</View>
```

Is there a way to fix that behaviour. I would really appreciate the help. Thank you.